# You can only create one profile per user

Tags: users

I cannot upgrade my user profile info in Drupal. After pressing submit this error message appears:

> This user already has a content profile of this type. You can only
>   create one profile per user.

and the name became red.  I am using the Content Profile module.

Comment: now I found out that this is problem of content profile. Because I have turned it off and everything works fine.

Comment: It seems that there is a conflict between contact profile module and filterform ui module. Setting exception in formfilter for profile content type seems to solve this problem.